# Nested Interval Theorem works in R?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Does the Nested Interval Theorem work for nonempty nested closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$? 
Is it possible to show that if $\{C_n\}$ is a collection of nonempty closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $C_{n+1}\subset C_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then $\cap A_n$ is nonempty?

Comment: $C_n=[n,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, as David's example $C_n = [n, \infty)$ shows. But this assertion can be generalized to [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_intersection_theorem) if you assume that the sets aren't just closed, but compact.